# Fill nan gaps in pandas df only if gaps smaller than N nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, nan

I am working with a pandas data frame that contains also nan values. I want to substitute the nans with interpolated values with `df.interpolate`, but only if the length of the sequence of nan values is =<N. As an example, let's assume that I choose N = 2 (so I want to fill in sequences of nans if they are up to 2 nans long) and I have a dataframe with

```
print(df)
A   B   C
1   1   1
nan nan 2
nan nan 3
nan 4   nan
5   5   5
```

In such a case I want to apply a function on `df` that only the nan sequences with length N<=2 get filled, but the larger sequences get untouched, resulting in my desired output of

```
print(df)
A   B   C
1   1   1
nan 2   2
nan 3   3
nan 4   4
5   5   5
```

Note that I am aware of the option of `limit=N` inside `df.interpolate`, but it doesn't fulfil what I want, because it would fill any length of nan sequence, just limit the filling to a the first 3 nans resulting in the undesired output

```
print(df)
A   B   C
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
nan 4   4
5   5   5
```

So do you know of a function/ do you know how to construct a code that results in my desired output? Tnx

Comment: You dont need any apply methods. Simply find the column names which agree with your condition and then use `df[cols]  = df[cols].interpolate()` to interpolate and overwrite them. Check my 2 liner for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform run length encoding and identify the runs of `NaN` that are shorter than or equal to two elements for each columns. One way to do that is to use `get_id` from package `pdrle` (disclaimer: I wrote it).

```
import pdrle


chk = df.isna() & (df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(pdrle.get_id(x)).transform(len)) <= 2)
df[chk] = df.interpolate()[chk]
#      A    B    C
# 0  1.0  1.0  1.0
# 1  NaN  2.0  2.0
# 2  NaN  3.0  3.0
# 3  NaN  4.0  4.0
# 4  5.0  5.0  5.0
```

Comment: Awesome, I like how it is short and it doesn't use explicit iteration in a for-loop. But can you tell a little bit about the `pdrle` package and in a 1-2 sentences what is happening in the one line of code `chk = ....`? Afterwards I can accept this as the answer to my question :) thanks

Comment: Also, the code runs quite slow - ~10 min for my 130000 rows in 10 columns. I think it is due to the `.groupby`. Do you think there is a way to speed up the code? tnx

Comment: Would `cython` or `numba` have an effect on the `.groupby` function applied to a dataframe? Can you give an example how this amendment should look like?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
N = 2
df_interpolated = df.interpolate()

for c in df:
    mask = df[c].isna()
    x = (
        mask.groupby((mask != mask.shift()).cumsum()).transform(
            lambda x: len(x) > N
        )
        * mask
    )
    df_interpolated[c] = df_interpolated.loc[~x, c]

print(df_interpolated)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0  5.0
```

---

Trying with different `df`:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  2.0
2  NaN  NaN  3.0
3  NaN  4.0  NaN
4  5.0  5.0  5.0
5  NaN  5.0  NaN
6  NaN  5.0  NaN
7  8.0  5.0  NaN
```

produces:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0  5.0
5  6.0  5.0  NaN
6  7.0  5.0  NaN
7  8.0  5.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following -

```
n=2
cols = df.columns[df.isna().sum()<=n]
df[cols]  = df[cols].interpolate()
df
```

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  4.0  4.0
4  5.0  5.0  5.0
```

---

`df.columns[df.isna().sum()<=n]` filters the columns based on your condition. Then, you simply overwrite the columns after interpolation.

Comment: Thanks! But my actual `df` is different from the dummy I show as an example - the real `df` is ~130 000 rows long and each column contains nan sequences of various length, some longer than N=2, some shorter. And I want in all the columns to fill sequences up to N long, so your answer will not do it. But still thanks :)